# gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require': no such file to load -- config/environment (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: jetbrains-ide

/home/sunil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/script/server
/home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require': no such file to load -- config/environment (MissingSourceFile)
=> Booting Mongrel
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in`require'
=> Rails 2.3.15 application starting on 
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in`require'
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/config.ru:1
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in`initialize'
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/config.ru:1
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/script/server:3:in`eval'
    from /home/sunil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/commands/server.rb:78
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/script/server:3:in `require'
    from /home/sunil/projects/neworders247/orders24-7-web/script/server:3

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while starting my ruby server on rubymine(jetbrain), but i was able to start server from commandline. I found the solution after so much hard surfing. Here is the solution:

Goto rubymine and edit your server configuration file and change the root directory of the your server configuration upto your project folder, there should not be any other path. In my case it was /script added at last , after removing this all was fine. Cheers.....

Thanks,
Sunil Kumar